# Class design to call member function of another class

Tags: c++

I am trying to design two class, such that I can call a member function of other class from the other class and pass a string argument.

For example if I have two classes `classA` and `classB`.  I want to be able to call from `Class::doSomething` method the `ClassB::ClassB_doit` method.

I have attempted via `ClassA registerCallback` to pass the `ClassB::classB_doit()` method and store it in a reference to class B.

I have tried in the attached code.  However, I am not sure how to achieve this.  Could someone point me in the correct direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class classB;

class classA {
public:
    classA ();
    ~classA ();
    void doSometing(std::string s) {
        x ();  // call member function in defined via registerCallback
    }
    void registerCallback(classB &t) {
        x = t;  // Store reference to member function
    }
private:
    classB & x;
};

class classB {
public:
    classB ();
    ~classB ();
    void classB_doit (std::string name) {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    classA A = classA();
    classB B = classB();
    A.registerCallback (B.classB_doit);
    A.doSometing("hello");   // Just to test call doSometing to force classB::classB_doit to be call
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x ();` → `x.classB_doit();`?

Comment: `classB & x;` is a reference to a class, not to a member function

Comment: You should look `std::function<void(const std::string&)>` or member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions). In addition, reference must be bound during initialization and the object to which it is bound cannot be changed, so you can use pointer instead.

```
class classA {
public:
    classA ();
    ~classA ();
    void doSometing(std::string s) {
        (x->*p)(s);  
    }
    void registerCallback(classB &t, void (classB::* _p)(std::string)) {
        x = &t;  
        p = _p;
    }
private:
    classB* x; // pointer instead of reference
    void (classB::* p)(std::string); // store pointer to member function
};
```

You can register the object and the member function like this:

```
A.registerCallback (B, &classB::classB_doit);
```